# ParseQuery Array to lowercase before search

Tags: java, android, arrays, parse-platform

I have issue with searching trough ParseQuery Array.

I need case insensitive search, so i need to convert my array to lowercase.

I tried query.whereMatches and query.whereContains without success.

My guess is to make new method that would convert all data from ParseQuery to lowercaseString Array.

Am i right with this one?

Here's the example code for setting search result list:

```
private void setList(boolean hardRefresh) {
    // stop any ongoing progress dialog
    cancelProgressDialog();

    reloadTags();
    reloadContents();
    ParseQuery<Note> query = Note.getQuery()
            .fromLocalDatastore()
            .orderByDescending("date");

    String searchStr = searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase();

    if (!searchStr.isEmpty()) {
        query.whereMatches(Note.FIELD_DETAIL, searchStr);
    }
    try {
        mNotes = query.find();
        if (adapter == null) {
            adapter = new ListAdapter();
            notesGridView.setAdapter(adapter);

        } else {
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For case insensitive search try like this :

```
if (!searchStr.isEmpty()) {
    query.whereMatches(Note.FIELD_DETAIL, searchStr,"i");
}
```